# Why this nonlinear fitting doesn't work?

Tags: fitting

I have the following data

```
setA = {{0.0001, 0.5, 0.5000000020621443`}, {0.01, 
    0.9090909090909091`, 0.9089263228218556`}, {0.1, 
    0.9803921568627451`, 0.9685612823447454`}, {1, 
    0.9951923076923077`, 0.8965347385041562`}, {10, 
    0.9975062344139651`, 0.8370285555286358`}, {1000, 
    0.9988901220865705`, 0.809761243637952`}, {10000, 
    0.9994556341861731`, 0.8080295675491966`}};

setB = {{0.0001, 0.5, 1.1754907046612933`*^-8}, {0.01, 
     0.9090909090909091`, 0.0001497516481925709`}, {0.1, 
     0.9803921568627451`, 0.013113265479399906`}, {1, 
     0.9951923076923077`, 0.36837218815129213`}, {10, 
     0.9975062344139651`, 4.605802823908744`}, {1000, 
     0.9988901220865705`, 495.77609116353705`}, {10000, 
     0.9994556341861731`, 4985.705218556087`}};;
```

which has the form $ \{\omega, \mu , a \}$ for setA and $ \{\omega, \mu , b \}$ for setB. Now I want to fit setA to
$$
\mu \Bigl(a_1-a_2 \text{erf}(\text{Log}[\omega]\sqrt{a_3 \mu})\Bigl)
$$
and fit setB to
$$
\lvert -b_1 \text{exp}\bigl( b_2 \text{Log}[\omega]\mu+ \frac{\mu \omega}{2} \bigr)  \rvert
$$
I tried these following codes

```
fitA = NonlinearModelFit[
  setA, \[Mu] (a1 - a2 Erf[Log[\[Omega]] Sqrt[a3 \[Mu]]]), {a1, a2, 
   a3}, {\[Mu], \[Omega]}]
```

and

```
fitB = NonlinearModelFit[setA, 
  Abs[-b1 Exp[b2 Log[\[Omega]]] \[Mu] + (b3 \[Mu] \[Omega])/2], {b1, 
   b2, b3}, {\[Mu], \[Omega]}]
```

but they don't work specially for setA. It returns this error:

```
NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value {-0.499987023189+0.0354938976555 I,-0.907628435515+5.02574192093 I,-0.955582409275+31.8756408087 I,-0.766746007804+242.692381728 I,0.46085875147 +4082.71039099 I,128.978969456 +5.26288648114*10^6 I,1297.07927743 +9.21370092281*10^8 I} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {7} at {a1,a2,a3} = {0.1297887307,987.212217384,-1981.56646201}.
```

Any idea to fit my data to formula?

**Addendum**

I  have determined the values of all these parameters using a two-step fitting (first, fit to $\omega$ and then fit to $\mu$). They have the following values which match to my real data:

$$
a_1=0.9,\;
a_2=0.096,\;
a_3=1.333,\;
b_1=0.1,\;
b_2=0.5
$$

but I want to reproduce them using a one-step fitting to make sure my results were true. In fact this is a cross-checking.

Comment: "They don't work", what error message do you get?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I added the error.

Comment: What do you mean by "your real data"?  That is different from `setA`?  Is your "2-step fitting" a recognized fitting technique?

Comment: I meant the correct values of parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the constraint `a3>0`

```
fitA = NonlinearModelFit[setA, {\[Mu] (a1 - a2 Erf[Log[\[Omega]] Sqrt[a3 \[Mu]]]), 
a3 > 0}, {a1, a2, a3}, { \[Omega]\[Mu]}]

fitA["BestFitParameters"]
(*{a1 -> 0.905805, a2 -> 0.0872282, a3 -> 2.49084}*)


Show[{ Plot3D[fitA[ \[Omega],\[Mu]], {\[Omega], 0, 10000}, {\[Mu], .5, 1},PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2]], Graphics3D[{Red, Point[setA]}] }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why you set $\mu$ from 0 to 10000? it's the range of $\omega$!

Comment: Please see the addendum

Comment: @wisdom See my corrected answer

Comment: Thanks it returns very better results, but a3 doesn't match to real a3. few data can be the reason? If I add more points to my data, it will yield the correct results?

Comment: @wisdom Probably yes!

Comment: @wisdom Take a look at `fitA["ParameterTable"]` and you'll see why the estimate of $a_3$ is just about worthless.  Always look at the measures of precision.  Also, the current dataset is limited not just in sample size but there are essentially just two different values for both predictors (one low and one high value).  You need not only more data points but those additional data points need more unique values for both predictors.